# matching columns one separate files and appending matches to file

Tags: awk

I'm trying to merge two files filtered on a single column using awk. What I'd then like to do is append the relevant columns from file2 into file 1.

Easier to explain with dummy example.

File1

```
name   fruit   animal
bob    apple   dog
jim    orange  cat
gary   mango   snake
daisy  peach   mouse
```

File 2:

```
 animal number  shape
 cat    eight   square
 dog    nine    circle
 mouse  eleven  sphere
```

Desired output:

```
 name   fruit   animal  shape   
 bob    apple   dog     circle
 jim    orange  cat     square
 gary   mango   snake   NA
 daisy  peach   mouse   sphere
```

Step 1: Need to filter on column 3 in file1 and column 1 in file2

`awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{c[$3]++;next};c[$1] > 0' file1 file2`

This gives me output:

```
cat    eight   square
dog    nine    circle
mouse eleven   sphere
```

This helps me somewhat, however I can't simply cut the third column (shape) from the output above and append it to to file1 since there is no entry for 'snake' in file2. I need to be able to append column 3 of output to file 1 where a match is successful, and where it is not to put 'NA'. It's essential that all the lines in file1 are retained so I can't just omit them. This is where I'm stuck!

I'd appreciate any help please....
E

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested based on shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$NF
  next
}
{
  print $0,($3 in a?a[$3]:"NA")
}'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                              ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  OFS="\t"                          ##Setting TAB as output field separator here.
}
FNR==NR{                            ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file file2 is being read.
  a[$1]=$NF                         ##Creating array a with index $1 and value is $NF for current line.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print $0,($3 in a?a[$3]:"NA")     ##Printing current line and checking if 3rd field is present in array a then print its value OR print NA.
}'  file2  file1                    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: You are a hero! Thank you! I should now be able to figure out how to do what I need for 100 columns and 30,000 lines :-D

Comment: @lecb, your welcome and happy learning on this great site cheers :)

Comment: I've applied the same approach to much larger file sizes and it seems to be hit and miss. I'm getting some 'NA' when there is indeed a match (and I've cross checked that what I'm matching is present in both files and in the correct column).

Not sure what is going on there! Unfortunately can't share data. What if, in my example above, I wanted to print both number and shape from file2 when there was a match?!

Comment: @lecb, not sure it worked for provided samples from you. Please try following to print number and shape both fro file2(not tested but should work) `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 OFS $NF;next} {print $0,($3 in a?a[$3]:"NA\tNA")}'  file2  file1`

Comment: Re above, I've figured out the issue. The awk script only works if the preceding columns to the one you're matching on (in file1) are non-blank. I managed to work around this using:

```awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = "NA" }; 1' file >new_File```

However, I'm still trying to figure out how I would output the 2nd column of file2 in addition to the third. I thought perhaps:

```awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$NF
  next
}
{
  print $0,$2,$3 in a?a[$3]:"NA"
}'  Input_file2   Input_file1```

This didn't work!

Comment: @lecb, sure, thank you for letting know cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @lecb if your input is tab-separated you should state that in your question. If some fields can be empty you should include that in the example in your question. All we have to go on to help you is what you tell us about your problem. wrt the 2 scripts in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344464/matching-columns-one-separate-files-and-appending-matches-to-file#comment110264681_62344612) - you figured out in the first script  that you have to set FS to `\t` and then you forgot to do so in the second one and you're reading file2 in the NR==FNR block so save $2 there with $NF.

Comment: @EdMorton I did state it was tab delimited (step one says so) and my dummy files are tab separated too.

My file is 100 columns and 30,000 lines, and only a couple of them were blank, I didn't know that to begin with as I subsetted on 100 lines to begin with (for which none were blank). I figured that out when troubleshooting - you've got to excuse a clinician for not going through every line before hand :-)!!!!

Comment: @lecb Having `-F'\t'` in part of a script that doesn't do what you want and hoping people will figure it out from that or hoping people will edit your question to see what the white space is in your examples (when copy/pasted they're blanks, not tabs) is a far cry from simply saying `I have these tab-delimited files` especially since without any empty fields or fields that contain blanks we have no reason to think/care about what the white space is between the fields anyway since awk will handle tabs or blanks or both the same way. I'm just saying for next time - state what the separator is.